# Unit Test failing on missing module via Angular dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to create a simple Unit Test which accesses a factory called `LimboExpenseService`.

```
angular.module( 'Trackee').factory( 'LimboExpenseService', require( './services/LimboExpenseService'))
```

My test looks like:

```
describe('LimboService', function() {
    var Limbo;
    beforeEach(module('Trackee'));


    it('should have a LimboExpenseService ', inject(['LimboExpenseService', function(LimboExpenseService) {
        expect(LimboExpenseService).toBeUndefined();
    }])); 
});
```

Problematically, I can't seem to grab that item via the `inject()` method.

What am I missing here?

Comment: you expect it to be undefined?

Comment: I actually expect it to be defined. But either way gave me the same error.

Comment: Try `var LimboExpenseSevice = angular.injector().get('LimboExpenseService');` instead.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work either... any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried not using the array syntax. Simply `inject(function(LimboExpenseService){...})`. If that doesn't work then obviously your module factory code just isn't loaded by the time you run the test.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `inject` function inside a `beforeEach` block. That should work.

Here's how:

```js
describe('LimboExpenseService', function() {
    var LimboExpenseService;
    beforeEach(module('Trackee'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_LimboExpenseService_){
     LimboExpenseService = _LimboExpenseService_;
    }))

    it('should have a LimboExpenseService ',function(){
     expect(LimboExpenseService).toBeDefined();
    }); 
});
```